# Term for a word that's a different word when spelled backwards

Tags: terminology

Palindromes are words, sentences, numbers that are the same forwards and backwards. Is there a term for words that are one word forwards but a different word backwards? For example, *star* backwards is *rats*, or *god* is *dog*.

Comment: The term is palindrome: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Palindrome

Comment: I don't understand the question. The palindromes of ***star, god*** are indeed ***rats, dog***, but I don't think anyone would normally say ***emordnilap*** is a palindrome of ***palindrome***, because *it's not a valid English word*.

Comment: It is, in fact, *not* palindrome. A palindrome requires the reading forwards and backwards to be the same. This question is clearly asking about words that are *still words* when backwards, but *different words*.

Comment: No, palindrome is a word that can be read both ways, also with a different meaning.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title in the future. Your original title applies to *every* question ever asked on this site. And do not use "questions" as a tag unless your question is *about* a question. Thank you.

Comment: Okay - I accept that *technically speaking*, a palindrome must read *identically* in either direction. But I'll leave my comment there, because I think in "loose parlance" (and for want of a better term), people do apply the term to OP's examples.

Comment: @Josh61: I have yet to find a definition for the word *palindrome* that does not also include the word *same*.

Answer (score 1):

The most common term for these is **Semordnilap** which is just the word palindromes backwards. A more understandable, albeit less fun, term is 'reverse anagram.'

See, e.g., [semordnilap](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/semordnilap)

Comment: Isn't "semordnilaps" doubly pluralized? I would think the singular form would be "emordnilap," and the plural form would be either "semordnilap" or "emordnilaps."

Answer (score -2):

According to Holman's Handbook to Literature 3rd Edition, a palindrome is "A word, sentence, or verse which **reads** the same from left to right and from right to left. 
A referral to "anagrams" is given, but nowhere (Erehwon!) is there mention of the construction you reference in this inquiry.

Comment: One source not including it is not evidence that there is no term for the phenomenon. (Not that the answer actually said there wasn't, so it doesn't actually answer the question at all, I'm afraid.)